# Need suggestion on multiple writer thread , single worker thread model

Tags: c, multithreading

I am writing a code in C where i have multiple writer(or feeder) threads which write into either high priority queue or low priority queue and a single worker (or consumer) thread which reads from both high priority queue and low priority queue.

I have a thread synchronization mechanism using pthread mutex.

I have one doubt in my mind at the time of writing this code i.e whether i should i have a separate lock for high priority queue and a low priority queue ?
or i should have a common lock for high and low priority queue.

Comment: Post your code.  There are ways to do this without any locks.

Comment: The way it stands now is far too broad. Post specifics, preferably the code if you can get it in a concise and understandable form.

Comment: Please find the pseudo code , as i can't paste the exact code .

Comment: typedef struct globals_s {
    
    /* feeder threads */
    pthread_t               thread_A;
    pthread_t               thread_B;
    pthread_t               thread_C;
    
    /* Worker thread */
    pthread_t               thread_W;


    /* queues and sync */
    dbl_qhead_t                work_q[WORKER_WORK_Q_MAX];
    pthread_mutex_t         work_q_mutex[WORKER_WORK_Q_MAX];
    pthread_cond_t          work_q_cond[WORKER_WORK_Q_MAX];

     /* Used to sync initialization */
    pthread_mutex_t         init_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t          init_cond;
    
} globals_t;

Comment: Sorry i am not able post the code , its big . How do i paste that code?

Comment: Edit your answer and post the code in the answer. Do not forget to use code formatting.

Answer (score -1):

> I have one doubt in my mind at the time of writing this code i.e whether i should i have a separate lock for high priority queue and a low priority queue ? or i should have a common lock for high and low priority queue.

Two locks will allow simultaneous writes to the high and low priority queues. A single lock will not.  Additionally, a single lock will prevent writing to *both queues* while reading items from *either* queue.  Thus two locks is going to perform better than one for *writes* as there is less lock contention.  For queue *read* performance, one lock is simpler to implement than two, but performs similarly.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using just one lock as it makes the implementation simpler and will likely result in better performance because of the simpler implementation. With a single lock, the reader implementation is just:

1. Acquire the lock.
2. Check the high priority queue, if there is work, take the work off the queue, unlock, do the work, and go to step 1.
3. Check the low priority queue, if there is work, take the work off the queue, unlock, do the work, and go to step 1.
4. Block on a single condition variable.
5. Go to step 1.